# How to send Counter metrics of RDS's Performance insights to cloudwatch or Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi Im trying to create alerts for My AWS services and i'm trying to collect the metrics like Aborted_connects,Aborted_clients,innodb_deadlocks for creating an alerts. I have enabled the performance insights and i can see the matrics in the performance insights page in RDS console. But only DBLoad,DBLoadCPU metrics are showing in cloudwatch. SO is there a way i can use these metrics to create an alerts from cloudwatch?
The rest of the metrics are in cloudwatch and Grafana.
How can i create alerts for the Counter metrics from Performance insights?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is completed. Couldn't find any direct way but with the help of Lambda function we can make it work and send the counter metrics to cloudwatch.
Please find the link to the solution:[https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/importing-amazon-rds-performance-insights-counter-metrics-to-amazon-cloudwatch/](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/importing-amazon-rds-performance-insights-counter-metrics-to-amazon-cloudwatch/)

Answer (score 0):

RDS Performance Insights and CloudWatch are more closely integrated now. Public docs have been updated to illustrate how to create CloudWatch alarms on your RDS Performance Insights database metrics:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/creating_alarms.html

For example, this page states: "You can use the DB_PERF_INSIGHTS metric math function in the CloudWatch console to query Amazon RDS for Performance Insights counter metrics. The DB_PERF_INSIGHTS function also includes the DBLoad metric at sub-minute intervals. You can set CloudWatch alarms on these metrics."